# Deep equal comparing not working on Cypress 9.7.0

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, cypress

I've updated my cypress to 9.7.0 version and right now I have a problem with **deep equal**. When I wrote test line of code:

```
expect([1,2,3]).to.deep.equal([1,2,3]);
```

[image]

Everything works correctly.

While I'm testing redux store I got an error which is looks

> Timed out retrying after 4000ms: expected [ Array(2) ] to deeply equal [ Array(2) ]

[image]

Arrays in devtool console preview are the same... I've tried in two ways to write test. I also combined it with async and timeouts

**First try:**

```
it('Example redux check', () => {
        cy.fixture('file.json').then((fixtures) => {
            cy.window()
                .its('store')
                .invoke('getState')
                .its('queue.queueItems').should('deep.equal', fixtures.store.queue.queueItems);
        });
    });
```

**Second try**

```
it('Example redux check', () => {
    cy.fixture('file.json').then((fixtures) => {
        const getQueueItems = (win) => {
            return win.store.getState().queue.queueItems;
        }

         cy.window()
             .pipe(getQueueItems)
             .should('deep.equal', fixtures.store.queue.queueItems);
    });
});
```

Had anyone similar issue or idea how to avoid that timeout? Exactly the same is happening while comparing async payloads...

Comment: Have you tried logging out the 2 arrays to confirm they are the same?

Comment: Yes, they're the same. I set test arrays to make sure. When I set timeout for example at 6000ms, cypress cannot finish task and comparing arrays as long as he can.

Comment: what content is in your real arrays?

Comment: Hello I got the same issue after upgrading. I will attempt to answer your question now.

Comment: @Dominic, in real I have a json object: array of an objects. But it also not working with smaller objects, like i.e. arrays

Comment: You might get a better idea of what's wrong with a proper diff output: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/4084#issuecomment-1052331722

Comment: But problem is not in that the objects are not equal. While you will try to compare x: {1,2,3,4} with y: {1,2,3,4} you get timeout error

Answer (score 1):

I also wanted to see if `deep.equal` on the `<h1>` element of `http://example.com` would succeed.

Here is my minimal, reproducible example.

```js
// Cypress 9.7.0

it('passes deep-equal of two DOM objects', () => {
  cy.visit('http://example.com')

  cy.get('h1').then($el1 => {                  // get h1 1st time
    cy.get('h1').then($el2 => {                // get another copy

      // Are they different objects?
      expect($el1).to.not.equal($el2)           // pass
      expect($el1 === $el2).to.equal(false)     // pass 

      // Do they deep-equal
      expect($el1).to.deep.equal($el2)          // pass
      
    })
  })
})
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Nearly all frontends I use have Cypress including some open source ones.

It is related to a few issues opened on GitHub and affects latest versions of Cypress.

https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/21353

https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/21469

This is what I get on a WIP after upgrading some tests that use `deep.equal`:

[image: Error with deep equal]

Your first example looks more standard.

I recommend downgrading to a lower version. The following version worked for me before upgrade:

`9.5.4`

Comment: I'm not sure you can use `deep.equal` on the text of an `<h1>` element.

Comment: @Fody You can because it is an object. It is a common usage in fact.

Comment: It's a jquery object - but what are you comparing it to?

Comment: I tried what I thought might be similar on example.com, but `deep.equal` did not fail.

Comment: Would like to reproduce your error shown above but cut off in the screen dump.

Comment: @Fody Both are DOM objects. They were working with the version specified. It is a common example. It is convenient to use "have.text" but normally decent we check the structure. If we have to convert the object to a string before comparison, it's a bit off IMHO.

Comment: So what exactly is the test?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't fault the `deep.equal` assertion in Cypress v9.7.0, even deeply nested arrays and objects - except when the order differed.

If your problem is difference in array order, try adding package `deepEqualInAnyOrder`

```js
const deepEqualInAnyOrder = require('deep-equal-in-any-order');
chai.use(deepEqualInAnyOrder);

it('matches when ordering is different', () => {
  
  const expected = [{a:{x:1}}, {b:2},{c:3}];

  expect([{a:{x:1}}, {b:2}, {c:3}]).to.deep.equal(expected)            // passes
  expect([{b:2}, {a:{x:1}}, {c:3}]).to.deep.equal(expected)            // fails

  expect([{b:2}, {a:{x:1}}, {c:3}]).to.deep.equalInAnyOrder(expected)  // passes

});
```